# How to combine Joined Inheritance with Secondary Table in JPA mappings?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have two classes engaged in inheritance.

```
BaseEntity creates a record in enrg table.
Website creates a record in ws table.
```

This is working fine. Now, I would like to add properties to Website that are common with other entities. I don't want to place them directly on Website entity, as that's a lot of duplication. At the same time, these properties are not common to all entities, so I don't want to add them to BaseEntity, either.

I have created a new class `PublishableEntity` where I have added these properties. Now, I'm trying to map Website in such a way, that

```
BaseEntity creates a record in enrg table.
PublishableEntity creates a record in pbdt table.
Website creates a record in ws table.
```

With the code below, the PublishableEntity is utterly ignored. I don't see any errors. It seems like the mapping is not even picked up by Hibernate.

**Classes**

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="entp", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@Table(name="enrg")
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

@SecondaryTable(name="pbdt", pkJoinColumns=@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="enid", referencedColumnName="enid"))
public abstract class PublishableEntity extends BaseEntity {

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("ws")
@Table(name="ws")
public class Website extends PublishableEntity {
```

Answer (score 0):

Only classes annotated with `@Entity`, `@Embeddable`, or `@MappedSuperclass` are scanned by the JPA provider.

You also might be missing the point of Secondary tables. Secondary table is indicating that a part of the entity is stored in this second table. For example:

```
@Entity
@SecondaryTable(name="ADDRESS",pkJoinColumns=@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="EMP_ID"))
public class Employee {
    @Id int id; // stored in table EMPLOYEE
    @Column(table="ADDRESS")
    String city; // stored in table ADDRESS
}
```

What you are probably aiming for is being able to identify Address as a type. For this you can create an Embeddable

```
@Embeddable
public class Address {
    String city;
}
```

that will be mapped to a different table in Employee. `city` attribute will be replaced by

```
@Embedded
@AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name="city", column=@Column(table="ADDRESS"))
})
Address address;
```

In your specific case `PublishableEntity` might become an embeddable.

Comment: That way I'm breaking normalization. PublishableEntity fields would have to be either part of BaseEntity table (wrong) or repeated in each concrete entity table (even worse). Also, I don't see how I'm missing the point on secondary tables..? Yes, part of an entity is stored in another table. That's exactly what I need and I want that inherited by multiple entities.